# Build a Firefox download manager type of GUI using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, user-interface

I am interested in building a simple GUI window using VB.net that looks more or less like the Firefox download manager (press Ctrl + J when you are in firefox to see how the window looks like). However, instead of Search, I would like to have a text space where I can enter the download URLs.

So basically, initially, I have a blank window with a clear list button and a URL text box at the bottom, as I type in the download URLs and press enter on keyboard, the text area at the top shows the download file name as well as the progress bar.

One more thing I would like to add is to have the window to automatically resize itself, meaning the more jobs I added to a list, the longer the size of the window will grow, up to a certain limit.

This is my first attempt on coding up something on the GUI side, so I am just wondering if there is anything to get me start with, is there like a package or library to get me started? Or, obviously preferably, is there already a package of something like this in VB.net?

Thanks!

Comment: No mention of winforms or WPF.  Punting: use FlowLayoutPanel

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the HTTPWebRequestClass and use it in conjunction with basic form laid out similar to the Firefox one. This will allow you to download files off the web. You can make it asynchronous so the UI doesn't hang.

Comment: Thanks, what I was looking for is more like the front end design, I have done back end ones before, but this is my first time designing the GUI part :)

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at Coder to Developer [UK](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Coder-Developer-Strategies-Delivering-Software/dp/078214327X)/ [US](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/078214327X), not only is it an excellent book (should be on all developers reading lists) but he builds a download manager in it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try to read off from this book then. Unfortunately I can not vote up yet, but thank you :)

Comment: No problem - I really can't rate it high enough.